# How to change the background by buttons on three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new in three.js and using the following code I want to know how to change the background by clicking a button. So I think there is something different than using "switch" and "break". Here is something with .loadTexture am I right?

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>gyroscopic</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                background-color: #000000;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container"></div>

        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="DeviceOrientationControls.js"></script>

        <script>
            (function() {
                  "use strict"

                  window.addEventListener('load', function() {

                        var container, camera, scene, renderer, controls, geometry, mesh;

                        var animate = function(){

                            window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                            controls.update();
                            renderer.render(scene, camera);

                        };

                        container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100);

                        controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls( camera );

                        scene = new THREE.Scene();

                        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 316, 18 );
                        geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( -1, 1, 1 ) );

                        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
                            map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'pic.jpg' )
                        } );

                        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        scene.add( mesh );

                        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 4, 4 );
                        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        scene.add( mesh );

                        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                        renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                        renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
                        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                        window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

                            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                        }, false);

                        animate();

                  }, false);

            })();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the texture using .loadTexture on a button click listener.

So you would probably add something like this to your HTML:

```
<button id="change-background">Change Background</button>
```

Then in Javascript:

```
var backgroundButton = document.getElementById('change-background');

backgroundButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
   material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('//new image path//');
});
```

You'll obviously need to replace the `//new image path//` with whatever URL you have for the new image.

The only question would be whether this updates the material on the mesh as well. I'm sure it does, but have no way of testing it at present.

Comment: The function is working but if I want 3 buttons I have to repeat the function every time?

Comment: That's right yes. If you want, you can extract this function into its own named function somewhere, and then just call it on click for each button with your new image path as an argument.